# "The server could not be contacted." error while deploying Model to SSAS

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular, analysisservices

I am able to deploy model to SSAS from SSDT but when i try to deploy to SSAS with http enabled SSAS seerver by following below article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/configure-http-access-to-analysis-services-on-iis-8-0?view=asallproducts-allversions&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-ver15

i get error : Server cannot be contacted, Issue attached as an image below:
[image]

How can i deploy to http enabled SSAS?

Answer (score 1):

For the database "RDSSAS" i have created a role for IUSR with full permissions and then depolyed the model using SSAS deployment wizard where i have given the servername as "http://localhost/OLAP/msmdpump.dll" then it got deployed.

Answer (score 1):

I had same error message in Visual Studio 2019. In Visual Studio 2022 the message was different: "Exception has been thrown by the target of invocation". The machine from which the deployment is run is not on the same domain. I added a Windows Credential - which allowed me to browse the cube from other tools. The user I added the credential for also has rights to deploy. The solution: "Run Visual Studio as Administrator". Worked in 2019 and 2022.